# Transforming result of function in snowflake within the function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to transform the result of my initial code to something I can change to be easier to read.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example.example.DEVICE_PARSER("LOB" VARCHAR(16777216), "PLATFORM" VARCHAR(16777216), "PLACEMENT" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN UPPER("LOB") = ''GCA'' THEN
                    CASE 
                        WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''LINKEDIN'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                        WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''TRADEDESK'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                        WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''TWITTER'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                        WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''META'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                        WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''QUANTCAST'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                        ELSE ''UNCLASSIFIED''
                    END
                ELSE ''UNCLASSIFIED''
            END AS device
        FROM (SELECT :LOB AS "LOB", :PLATFORM AS "PLATFORM", :PLACEMENT AS "PLACEMENT")
    )
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN UPPER(device) = ''MOB'' THEN ''Mobile''
            WHEN UPPER(device) = ''DESKTOP'' THEN ''Desktop''
            WHEN UPPER(device) = ''TABLET'' THEN ''Tablet''
            ELSE INITCAP(device)
        END AS result
    FROM cte;
';
```

But I am getting a L compilation result error.

I tried this code below however I wish to do it in a single function

```
-- Create a separate function for the transformation
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform_device(device VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
    CASE
        WHEN UPPER(device) = ''MOB'' THEN ''Mobile''
        WHEN UPPER(device) = ''DESK'' THEN ''Desktop''
        WHEN UPPER(device) = ''TAB'' THEN ''Tablet''
        ELSE INTCAP(device)
    END;
';

-- Modify the original function to call the transformation function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example.example.DEVICE_PARSER("LOB" VARCHAR(16777216), "PLATFORM" VARCHAR(16777216), "PLACEMENT" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
    CASE
        WHEN UPPER("LOB") = ''GCA'' THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''LINKEDIN'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''TRADEDESK'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''TWITTER'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''META'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                WHEN UPPER("PLATFORM") = ''QUANTCAST'' THEN SPLIT_PART("PLACEMENT", ''_'', 4)
                ELSE ''UNCLASSIFIED''
            END
        ELSE ''UNCLASSIFIED''
    END AS device,
    transform_device(device) AS result
';
```

For example in the placements below I would expect the results Mobile, Desktop and Tablet respectively given they are all GCA LOB.

| LOB | Platform | Placement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GCA | Meta | a_b_c_Des_e |
| GCA | Twitter | a_b_c_mob_e |
| GCA | Tradedesk | a_b_c_TAB_e |

Comment: Hi - what's the compilation error you are getting? Shouldn't the line " WHEN UPPER("LOB") " be "WHEN UPPER(:LOB) "?

Comment: It's also easier if you delimit your code block with $$ and then you don't have double single quotes everywhere. You also seem to have a typo in ELSE INTCAP(device) - it should be INITCAP

Comment: Yes sorry INITCAP was typo, The error I am getting is Syntax error:L compilation error: (line 2), syntax error line 2 at position 4 unexpected 'WITH'.
syntax error line 3 at position 8 unexpected 'SELECT'.
syntax error line 5 at position 42 unexpected 'THEN'. (line 2)

Comment: 1) Use $$ and remove all the repeated single quotes to make your code easier to read/debug 2) Remove the double quotes round your input parameters in the SP definition and the SQL statement 3) Remove the ";" at the end of the SQL statement

Comment: @NickW In the new console of snowflake you cannot use the $$ for functions.

Comment: By "new console" do you mean Snowsight? If so then you can use $$ in functions - I re-wrote and tested your function using the suggestions I made in my last comment before I posted the comment. I'm not sure why you think you can't use $$?